# Standard way of finding binaries?

Tags: linux, posix

Is there a function or a well-proven snippet to resolve the path to a binary (via $PATH and stuff)
in order to start an application using exec* or similar functions?

Comment: Why do you want the path if you are just going to run it?  exec should respect the PATH parameters.

Comment: @Jiminion, that, plus maybe a pull quote from the `exec(3)` man page describing the behavior of `execp` / `execlp` was probably the answer the OP was looking for. If one were new to this, and all one knew about was `execve`, it's a legit question. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `exec` variants with `p` in their names, they automatically search `$PATH`. So use `execlp` or `execvp` and it's taken care of for you.

There's no "and stuff" I'm aware of -- when not given a pathname, the only way to find binaries is via `$PATH`.